# Changing an iframe's background when loading

Tags: html, css, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change or control the color of the IFRAME area before the content loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530943/can-i-change-or-control-the-color-of-the-iframe-area-before-the-content-loads)

I have an iframe on in a div, with a background colour. When the page is loading, the iframe placeholder turns white. Is there any way to change the background when an iframe is loading?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/" width="500" height="400" style="background-color: red;"></iframe>
```

Would work?

You could also give the iFrame a Class or ID and give it CSS styles.

For images:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/" width="500" height="400" style="background-image: url('http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_uk/images/logo.gif');"></iframe>
```

- Barrie